# Getting Framework related warning in Xcode 7.0

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks, xcode7

error I'm receiving is this

> directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

I have no idea why this is coming is this related to framework ?

Comment: You can solve it by creating a new project. I had the same problem. The projects settings most options disappeared

Comment: it's quite tough to create a new project its like starting from zero

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810874/getting-framework-related-warning-in-xcode-7-2

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I get rid of these by finding the target(s) that generated the error, then removing/deleting the (odd) path in the "Framework Search Paths" build setting:

[image: specific build setting]

Comment: Mine was in the test target. Check all your targets for the erroneous search path.

Comment: You can also make the script happy by creating the directory Frameworks at the path /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/

Comment: I'm getting this same error on my test target as well. Even if I leave the `Framework Search Paths` for debug as the inherited value "$(inherited)", I still get the error. Seems like a bug with Xcode. I have no `Framework Search Paths` defined at the Project level, I'm not for sure where these inherited search paths are coming from.

Comment: resolved issue with Xcode7.1+iOS SDK9.1 (testing target had this setting set)

Comment: I have two projects and one of them I started a new project and imported all the files to resolve this, then when this showed up in the other one and I forgot how I fixed it...I found this and it totally worked..I only deleted the second entry in the list not the $(inherited) path which doesn't show up, but it didn't seem to matter even when I tried to delete everything from all targets, both resolved the issues

Answer (score 33):

What solves this for me is to create a new scheme.  Click on Product-> Scheme -> New Scheme and just hit OK.
Then my app seems to build and run.

Comment: I didn't have any thing in my search path to delete, creating a new scheme fixed it for me...

Comment: I also had no paths to delete, and this solution removed the error for me.

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer, which didn't work me.

Answer (score 24):

After much digging, I found this is actually related to my test target of my app.

[image]

The Fix

If you select your project, and look under ‘Targets’, you should see two targets. One is your app and the other one is your test. Under ‘Search Paths’ (in my test target), I found it was including two items under ‘Framework Search Paths’:

$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks
$(inherited)

[image]

Deleting those entries in my older project then removed the warning. I did not have to make any changes to the other target.

Comment: Do you know why this Framework Search Path was there in the first place?  Should there have been nothing or was the incorrect path there?  Deleting it removed my warnings.  However, I'd like to know why the incorrect path was there  I'm wondering if it's because a folder name was changed between updates or something.  As @marmaralone mentioned, I had the `PrivateFrameworks` folder instead of the `Frameworks` folder.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of deleting Framework Searh Paths (It causes other problems specially if you're using Fabric framework), you can change this line :

> $(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks

with

> $(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks

and it should work.

Comment: I noticed I had the `PrivateFrameworks` instead of the `Frameworks` folder.  Do you know why there is the discrepancy?

Comment: According to Apple documents, "If multiple applications must share a private framework, you should install the framework in one of the available PrivateFrameworks directories on the system rather than embed it in one (or all) of the applications." Probably you are using a framework that shared with multiple applications (generally caused by Crashlytics)

Answer (score 0):

Please, let me this contribution.

I had this problem working with Xcode 8.0 (8A218a) and for a iOS Deployment Target 10.

Concretely, **Xcode could not read the MapKit.framework**. Error message said:

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Admin/Documents/APPS/PeekaWish/PeekaWish/MapKit.framework/MapKit, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Admin/Documents/APPS/PeekaWish/PeekaWish/MapKit.framework/MapKit (3 slices)

**The worst thing was that I had not made any changes. The inconsistency apparently occurred after a bad Product Build** (My project folder appear duplicated on the Xcode Editor, on Left Side, the Navigator Bar)

**I lost a lot of time: linking repeatedly the MapKit.framework**

Finally, I found the solution. It is a mix of above solutions.

> 1 STEP: Click on Product-> Scheme -> New Scheme and just hit OK

**On TARGETS (the App) and Build Settings:**

> 2 STEP: Deleting Framework Search Paths (leave these fields empty)
>
> 3 STEP: Always Search User Paths -> NO